# I want Update Qty from Table in SQL, From cheking MIN(ExpDate) and barcode

Tags: mysql

## SQL_Update Question..

A Table Can have multiple items under a same barcode with different ExpDate

For example:

```
1.* ExpDate - 2019.05.05,
      Qty - 45,
      SellPrice - 150.00,
      Barcode - 2,

2.* ExpDate - 2020.08.01,
      Qty - 34,
      SellPrice - 230.00,
      Barcode - 2,
```

I want to update qty, when barcode is 2 and MIN(ExpDate)

Comment: What about ties? meaning two records with the same barcode and same min ExpDate  exists how would should that be handled?

Comment: Barcode in this table is foreign key. If i Have Item as apple, thins it barcode as 2. But  it can have with different exp date

Answer (score 1):

You could use a join with a subquery for min date

```
update  my_table  m
inner join  (
  select  barcode, min(ExpDate) min_date
  from my_table  
  group by  barcode
) t on t.barcode = m.barcode and t.min_date = m.expdate 
where m.barcode = 2 
set qty = Your_value
```

Comment: topicstarter keep in mind that this query assumes that the barcode, (min) expdate combo are unique, if two record with the same barcode with the same min date exists both will be updated.

Comment: thanks sir, your cord is not worked in my pc, but it is worked when i edit it like this   update  TblStock  m
 inner join
 (
  select  TblMedicine_barcode, MIN(ExpDate) min_date
  from TblStock  
  where TblMedicine_barcode = 2
  group by  TblMedicine_barcode  
 )t on t.TblMedicine_barcode = m.TblMedicine_barcode and t.min_date = m.expdate 
 set Qty=800